# ServiceStack + Razor + Auth + Fluent Validation

Tags: razor, servicestack

I am building a very simple `ServiceStack` website using the built-in SS Razor, Auth, and Fluent validation.  I've set up a simple login page, but if there is any sort of failure, I'm shown the SS `Snapshot of Authenticate generated by ServiceStack` page.

```
login.cshtml

<form action="@(new Authenticate() { provider = "credentials" }.ToPostUrl())" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="hidden" name="continue" value="@(new Home().ToGetUrl())" />
</form>


AppHost.cs (Configure snippet)

        TimeSpan slidingExpiry = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        var authProvider = new CredentialsAuthProvider()
        {
            SessionExpiry = slidingExpiry
        };

        AuthFeature authFeature = new AuthFeature(
           () => new AuthUserSession(),
           new IAuthProvider[] { authProvider },
            htmlRedirect: new Login().ToGetUrl()
           );

        authFeature.IncludeAssignRoleServices = false;
        authFeature.IncludeRegistrationService = false;
        authFeature.IncludeAuthMetadataProvider = false;
```

I'd like to be able to trap this and display a razor view with the errors, instead of being required to do an AJAX call to authenticate.  How can I set up my website to show a razor view for authentication failures?

Comment: Reading through the SS Razor docs, on a whim I tried creating a 'Views/Authenticate.cshtml' page.  Lo and behold that seems to work!  The URL isn't pleasant (/auth/credentials), but I can work with that.

Answer (score 2):

Following [API First development](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/EmailContacts#api-first-development) and using Ajax is definitely the preferred approach for handling Fluent Validation errors.

This FORM POST's to the `Authenticate` Service which requires its own Razor Views in order to show a different HTML Representation. So you'd need to add `Authenticate.cshtml` or `AuthenticateResponse.cshtml` View Pages to handle the Response of the Authenticate Service.

Comment: Figured as much around AJAX.  I'm eyeballing a very limited client (think industrial controls), and wanted to see if I could get away with not having jQuery / jQuip at all.